# how to handle onSnapshot of firebase 9 in angular component and service

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have running my application perfectly with

> "@angular/fire": "^6.1.5",
> "firebase": "^8.6.3",

and it was like

Service.ts

```
getUserEventSummary(userId) {
this.firestore.collection(`/user/${userId}/event_summary`).doc('current').snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes => changes.payload.data())
    );
}
```

Component.ts

```
this.service.getUserEventSummary(this.userId).subscribe((res: any) => {
    this.values = res;
}
```

And such code is all over the application.
Now I have moved to the latest version of firebase that is

> "firebase": "^9.0.1",
> "@angular/fire": "^7.0.4",

And new changes are

service.ts

```
getUserEventSummary(userId) {
 
 return onSnapshot(doc(db, 'general_lookup', 'onboarding_page'), (document) => {
      return document.data();
  });
}
```

And component.ts

```
const data = this.homeService.getOnboaringCollection();
console.log(data);
```

But I am getting nothing on console.

As per described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#web-version-9_1)  Looks like I have to manage it inside component file.
Does it is only option to work with `onSnapshot` ?

Please help me with a better approach than changing the code of components.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After lots of digging I was able to find the following solution that will allow you to return the snapshots in a similar fashion that `snapshotChanges` previously would.

Service:

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {doc, docSnapshots, Firestore} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import {map} from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ExampleService {

  constructor(private firestore: Firestore) {}

  async getUserEventSummary() {
    const ref = doc(this.firestore, 'general_lookup', 'onboarding_page');
    return docSnapshots(ref).pipe(map(data => data.data()));
  }
}
```

Component:

```ts
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ExampleService} from "./services/example.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service: ExampleService) {}

  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    const doc$ = await this.service.getUserEventSummary();

    doc$.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    })
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, the documentation isn't as clear or in depth as it could be because Firebase 9 is still so new but with time it'll surely improve.

Comment: Oh my days, this was driving me mad.  Thanks.  Works well.